# IONIC 3 - erro ao gerar build - ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugin, build

Fala garela, bom estou com um problema ao tentar fazer o build de uma aplicação IONIC 3, segue os dados abaixo do ambiente e dos erros que estou tendo, se alguem já passou por isso e conseguiu a solução e puder ajudar, já agradeço!

## ionic info

cli packages: (/home/robinson/Documentos/myProject/my-app/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v7.7.3
npm               : 4.1.2 
OS                : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /home/Android/Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

## cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: installed android-27,android-26

Gradle: installed /usr/lib/gradle/4.3.1/bin/gradle

## Erro gerado após rodar o: ionic cordova build android --prod --release

:transformClassesWithDexForArmv7Release
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForArmv7Release'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzo;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 42.291 secs
Error: /home/robinson/Documentos/myProject/my-app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForArmv7Release'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzo;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release (exit code 1).

Answer (score 0):

Bom, deixei meu ambiente com:

```
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
```

e tirei o plugin do firebase:

```
npm remove  @ionic-native/firebase

ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
```

subistitui pelo https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

dessa forma compila,
se atualizo para o android 7.0 buga, então estou trabalhando dessa forma por enquanto!

Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Esse é um problema bem chato de se analisar, possivelmente está ocorrendo inconsistência de versões de bibliotecas que especificam o Play Services.

Tente entrar no seu arquivo project.properties e verificar as versões das bibliotecas. Uma sugestão é tentar deixar as mesmas iguais, você pode fazer essas alterações no próprio arquivo